# Set up Spring Boot application.properties file with database url/username/password in an .env file

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

So instead of having my database's url/user/password stored as plain text in the file, I want to access them through .env file stored on my project's root directory (where gradlew and build.gradle is located).

Though I haven't found a good answer how to go about this solution and others only give solutions by creating environment variables on the system itself.

I've tried creating a separate class utilizing io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv dependency and creating a class that loads the .env file to be used in my applications.properties file like so, but it's unable to find it.

EnvConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class EnvConfig {

    @Bean
    public Dotenv dotenv() {
        return Dotenv.configure().ignoreIfMissing().load();
    }
    
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=${dotenv.get('DB_URL')}
spring.datasource.username=${dotenv.get('DB_USER')}
spring.datasource.password=${dotenv.get('DB_PASS')}
```

Even if it was a simple fix to my code, are there better solutions to this and what would be the best practice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do here won't work because the properties are loaded before the bean is created.  Plus, that's not the correct syntax for SpEL to invoke methods on beans.  If you want to externalize these to a file, try something like this:

1. Ditch the dotenv thing, you won't need this.
2. Create a file called .env.properties that contains the values you want
3. Add this configuration to your application properties

   spring.config.import=optional:file:.env.properties
4. Any property defined in .env.properties is available for injection via `@Value`

The location of the `.env.properties` file is important, it needs to be in the current working directory of the running java process.  You can also use absolute paths here, like     `spring.config.import=optional:file:/opt/secure/.env.properties`, or, better yet, you can replace the path with a variable reference and set an environment variable like this. `spring.config.import=optional:file:${ENV_FILE}`, `export ENV_FILE=/opt/secure/.env.properties`.

I prefer to use Vault for stuff like this.

Comment: How would I go about injecting the datasource url/user/pass? So far I've created .env.properties file in the root of my project generated by Spring init where build.gradle is located. Would this be the right spot?

Comment: @Jacob I'm not sure what you mean by how would you inject the datasource url/user/pass.  If you are asking where you would define those, you can put those values directly as properties into your .env.properties file.  The .env.properties file is nothing more than a spring properties file. You can locate that file anywhere you want, just pass in the path to spring.config.import.